# How to handle images in a blog feed?

Tags: image, rss, feed

This seems like a basic thing to do, but I don't see an obvious best practice on the web.

1. What's the best way to include images in a blog feed, and
2. What's the best way to parse the feed and serve the image on a webpage on a different domain?

Any answers would be awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible ways to "handle" images: enclosures and in the body of the description tag. If they are large images, use enclosures. If they're small, embed them in the description tag and set its content-type to be html.

The line between "large" and "small" seems arbitrary, however.

Comment: Just wanted to follow up on this, as this answer is close to correct. I solved this by using the `<content:encoded>` node, which I think is what you're referring to. This is what it turns out is RSS best practice for passing code. Once that is in the feed with `<![CDATA[` wrapper, the image and content is passed along, encoded in html if present. Then you can parse it by getting the namespace _content_.

Comment: Could you link to the source for "RSS best practices"?

Comment: Sure, try this: [RSS best practices on Namespace Elements](http://www.rssboard.org/rss-profile#namespace-elements-content-encoded)

Comment: Did that help? I think I'm reading it correctly, but just wanted to see what you thought.